# comparing two Lists in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I have two Lists, and I've values in these as,

```
List1                  List2
-----                  -----
 1                      1
 2                      2
                        3
```

I've to compare the second list with the first list, and I've to return the values which is not in the `List1`(here "3"), how can we compare two lists like this?

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use LINQ and the [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) extension method.

```
var list1 = new List<int> { 1, 2 };
var list2 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var remaining = list2.Except(list1);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
var result = list2.Except(list1);
```

Note that it's considered bad style to use initial capitals on your variable names (unless they're actually properties) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx

Rarest examples on msdn which i found useful.